# What are recent AI software systems and research papers close to J. Pitrat's ideas?

Tags: reference-request, symbolic-ai, meta-learning, meta-rules

[J. Pitrat](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Pitrat) (born in 1934) was a French leading artificial intelligence scientist (the first to get a Ph.D. in France mentioning "artificial intelligence"). His [blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) is still online and of course refer to most of his papers (e.g. [*A Step toward an Artificial Artificial Intelligence Scientist*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2117/9600b3f05c0af399f9acbfc6e7b6d24daf03.pdf), etc.) and books, notably [*Artificial Beings: the conscience of a conscious machine*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470611791) (his last book). He passed away in October 2019. I attended (and presented a [talk](http://refpersys.org/Starynkevitch-CAIA-RefPerSys-2020mar06.pdf)) at a [seminar](https://afia.asso.fr/journee-hommage-j-pitrat/) in his memory.

*What are recent AI systems or research papers related to the idea of symbolic AI, introspection, declarative metaknowledge, meta-learning, meta-rules, etc.?*

Most of those I know are more than 20 years old (e.g. Lenat [Eurisko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurisko); I am aware of [OpenCyC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyc#OpenCyc)). I am interested in papers or systems published after 2010 (perhaps [AGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence) papers with *actual* complex open source software prototypes).

-see also the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) system-

Answer (score 1):

Today one of the challenges is learning representations/concepts that are causally invariant. Once we have good representations then we can work on the reasoning aspect. There are 2 camps of people today. One believes that symbolic manipulation cannot be achieved properly by deep networks. Hence, they separate the task of extracting a lower-dimensional representation of objects from the visual scenes from the task of reasoning with knowledge-graphs. The other camp feels that we can do end-to-end training of a neural network and it can learn how to jointly learn a good lower-dimensional representation for each symbol along with learning how to reason with them. I am no expert at this but here are a few papers that I find are worthy for you to read -

1. Neuro Symbolic Concent Learner [Paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rJgMlhRctm), [Code](https://github.com/vacancy/NSCL-PyTorch-Release)
2. Learning Reasoning Strategies in End-to-End Differentiable Proving [Paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/minervini20a/minervini20a.pdf), [Code](https://github.com/uclnlp/ctp)
3. Neuro-Symbolic Visual Reasoning: Disentangling “Visual” from “Reasoning” [Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11524v3.pdf)
4. Knowledge Infused Learning (K-IL):
   Towards Deep Incorporation of Knowledge in Deep Learning [Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.00512.pdf)
5. Visual Concept-Metaconcept Learning [Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.01464.pdf) [Project Page](http://vcml.csail.mit.edu/)
6. CVPR 2020 workshop on Neuro-Symbolic Visual Reasoning and Program Synthesis [youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Opunfo422uQ&list=PLX0h2D8LfCPHtT0-u6xjYaGFPT6-3cLJ1&index=1&ab_channel=NSCV%2720)

If you are looking for community maintained lists, here is one  [list of papers](https://github.com/ccclyu/awesome-deeplogic)